# MySQL time offset (Range from within a Range)

Tags: .net, mysql, datetime, subquery

I have a advanced search function that queries records based on date & time. I want to return all records between a datetime range and then from within that range I want to narrow the results to a range of hours (eg May 1st 2012 - May 7th 2012 and show records from 2pm to 7pm).

What I did was add a time field in the database then used an AND statement to look at the time field. This worked fine until I started offseting the datetime and time fields by a number of hours to adjust from differnt time zones. The problem with this is when the time field is offset by lets say 6 hours a valid time query like <=2pm<=7pm ends up with <=8pm<=1am which will return zero results.

Is there a better way to do this?

Query:

```
SELECT Id, Item, 
       LEFT(DAYNAME(Date - INTERVAL 0 HOUR),3) as DayofWk, 
       CONCAT('$',FORMAT(Sale,2)) AS Sale, 
       CONCAT('$',FORMAT(Retail,2)) AS Retail,
       Date, Time, Winner 
  FROM masterdata2 
 WHERE Item LIKE '%xbox%' 
   AND Date BETWEEN CONCAT('2010-6-28', ' ', '00:00:00') + INTERVAL 0 HOUR 
            AND CONCAT ('2012-7-9',' ','23:59:00') + INTERVAL 0 HOUR 
   AND time BETWEEN CONCAT ('2010-6-28',' ','00:00:00') + INTERVAL 0 HOUR 
            AND CONCAT ('2012-7-9',' ','23:59:00') + INTERVAL 0 HOUR 
   AND ( Dayofwk != 'Mon' || Dayofwk != 'Tue' || Dayofwk != 'Wed' || Dayofwk != 'Thu' || Dayofwk != 'Fri' || Dayofwk != 'Sat' || Dayofwk != 'Sun' )
```

Comment: Is there a reason you have date and time separate?

Comment: Don't use `BETWEEN` for date and datetime queries: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Comment: I thought by using time as a separate field I could further restract the query results. If I can do everything from the datetime variable then I would.

Comment: Looking into this further I think I need a nested SELECT statement or a subquery, but I am not sure how to write it.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the following MySQL functions:

- [DATE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date)
- [TIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time)
- [CONVERT_TZ()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)
- [CAST()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast)

Using the first two, you could only use one datetime field instead of two, which – if I understand you correctly – contain the exact same values? With the third, you can convert datetimes between timezones. The last one is used to cast to a specific type, in this case something like `CAST('22:00:00' AS TIME)` => `January, 01 1970 22:00:00-0800`.

- Why do you compare the time against datetimes? As you said, you first limit the results to **all** items between two calendar dates and then to just the items between two times **on those dates**. This would mean something like this:

```sql
    [...]
    AND (DATE(sold) BETWEEN CAST('2010-06-20' AS DATE) AND CAST('2012-07-20' AS DATE))
    AND (
       (TIME(sold) >= CAST('22:00:00' AS TIME))
       OR
       (TIME(sold) <= CAST('02:00:00' AS TIME))
    )
    [...]
```

- As I understand it, your query fails if the times that were offset span over two days (or even noon and midnight?). I guess what you need to do is to detect this and increment your max date by 1 (from `2012-07-09` to `2012-07-10`) if you want to catch all items in that night (as well as treat the starting date as well).
- If I get it wrong, could you elaborate on why your query fails? `8pm < x < 1am` is a valid timespan, so why are you not getting any results?

It would really help if you provide a short `CREATE TABLE` statement and some sample data. That way, one could play around with the queries.

Comment: This seems to work with 22:00:00 and 02:00:00, but when I pug in lets say 12:00:00 and 22:00:00 then all the results are returned however onlt results 1 and 6 should be returned. Plus I some how need to compensate for a time offset (+1-6hrs). How would I do this?

Comment: **12-22**: You would then need to change the `OR` to `AND` (resultset contains 1 and 6 as you said). — **Offset**: You could convert all times in the timezone or add the offset before you build your query. I probably would go and go the latter way. Add the offset in your code and then dynamically build the query (check if the time interval lies within the same day or overlap midnight).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, lets try this (im new so go easy on me):

```
CREATE TABLE abc (ID INT(255) UNSIGNED ZEROFILL,sold DATETIME);
INSERT INTO abc (ID, sold) VALUES
(1,'2012-06-01 18:00:00'),
(2,'2012-06-20 23:00:00'),
(3,'2012-07-01 00:00:00'),
(4,'2012-07-10 01:00:00'),
(5,'2012-07-15 02:00:00'),
(6,'2012-07-20 12:00:00');
SELECT ID, sold
FROM abc
WHERE
(DATE(sold) BETWEEN '2012-06-20' AND '2012-07-20')
AND
(TIME(sold) BETWEEN '23:00:00' AND '02:00:00');
```

This creates a table and runs a query. The results should return #2-#5, but I return zero results because there is no such thing as between 18:00:00 AND 02:00:00. There is however data BETWEEN 2:00:00 AND 18:00:00. The problem is if I am offsetting the time by + hours then there will be times I will have 18:00:00 AND 02:00:00. How do I do this?

My data is all in EDT. Should I be using a timezone function?

Thank you for the help!!

Comment: Please see my edit. I split the TIME clause and used `>=` and `<=` operators. This makes sense, when the beginning or end of a day (12am/12pm) would be needed in the `BETWEEN` statement. For your timezone issues, you should look up the `CONVERT_TZ()` function.

Comment: By the way, your code helped a lot. I was able to set up your schema over on [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/de00e/7/0) and run the query (does not work for me in Chrome though, Firefox and Safari ok).